# Dynamically change an input field's placeholder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, d3.js

I am working with Javascript and the d3 library, and AngularJS.

Is there a way to dynamically change an input box's placeholder? I am working with a calendar widget and multiple views and wanted to see if there was a way to have the placeholder always be the value that was last inputted into the field.

I wrote a small function that always returns the last thing that was entered into the input field...but then when I tried setting placeholder=functionIwrote() it literally makes the placeholder "fucntionIwrote()" instead of running the function.

Comment: `placeholder` is not an event, what do you expect? You are using jQuery, it has `attr` method, `attr('placeholder', 'newValue')`

Comment: the problem is that I'm using angular controllers...I have a controller where I am trying to change the placevalue of input fields in the view file. I think this should work: d3.select(".classNameofInputField").attr("placeholder", "hello"); but it doesnt work..

Comment: I have provided an answer in jQuery where there're event listeners such that whenever the value of an `input` is updated, the `placeholder` will be updated automatically.

Comment: A placeholder is meant to describe the *generic* pattern of expected input, not some specific value. If you have a useful *default value* e.g. from previous input, make it the default by putting it into the `value` attribute (property) and omit the `placeholder` attribute as not needed.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment but... If you're using angularJs, you just have to bind the model of your input to the placeholder!

```
<input type="date" placeholder="myModel" ng-model="myModel" />
```

This way, your input would always be the latest filled value.

If you want to change your view, and then retrieve datas, then you have to store them outside of the controller scope - which is "cleaned" every time if you're using the ngIf directive -.

A good way to do this is to use a service as persistance layer.

Comment: hmmm I thought it would something as simple as this...but setting my placeholder="MyModel" literally sets it to be the string myModel

      <text class="dateSelection1">From: </text><input ui-date id="startvalue" placeholder="startDate" ng-model="startDate"><text class="dateSelection">To: </text><input ui-date placeholder="endDate" id="endvalue" ng-model="endDate">

I already have the values stored using a service that makes query calls.

Comment: Oh sorry; I didn't try ;-)ng-attr-placeholder will cause the expression to be evaluated, and must fix you problem. Otherwise, you still can use an <input placeholder="{{ myModel }}" />. Double bracket would also cause the expression to be evaluated, with the angular two way binding :-)

Comment: Is there a way to use both the regular place holder and the ng placeholder? I'm currently working on a search input..and when the user hasnt type anything in I want it to say "Search for entries" but then when they type something, I want them to be able to switch between views, maintaining that search in the input..but if they delete what they typed in, I want it to say "Search for entries" again

Comment: You must have to init the binded model to the default value. and reset it when he clear the input - without any choice if this is what you want -

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the `placeholder` to be changed or updated both `automatically` and `dynamically`, you may use the jQuery code below:

```
$(function() {
    $('input').on('change blur', function() {
        !this.value || $(this).attr('placeholder', this.value);
    });
});
```

[**WORKING JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/SAX26/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it in this way ,

```
<input 
placeholder="Select Date" 
onfocus="(this.type='date')" 
onblur="if (!this.value) this.type = 'text'">
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bBh3L/

'placeholder' is an element attribute, so you can use $('#myInput').attr(attributeName, attributeValue) to set it.

In this case, I mapped the button click to change the placeholder using:

```
$('#myInput').attr('placeholder', 'new one');
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you're trying to wrap your calendar widget into an angular directive, if so, here's what I did for a similar use case (I display the accepted/valid format as placeholder):

```
module.directive('yourDirective', [function() {
  return {
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $controller) {

      // bind 'yourValue' (the one you want to show as placeholder) in the scope
      $scope.$watch('yourValue', function(value) {
        $attrs.$set('placeholder', value);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There exists a conditional attribute property in **AngularJS** `ng-attr-{property_name}`

For example, I'm using different placeholders for different search options using

```
 ng-attr-placeholder="{{isAdvanceSearch ? setPlaceholder(searchOption) : 'John Smith, 08/23/1970, 123'}}"
```

Here on the basis of `isAdvanceSearch` variable, I'm setting different placeholders in `setPlaceholder` method.

`setPlaceholder` method returns the placeholder to set in the input field.

```
$scope.setPlaceholder = function(searchOption) {
     if (searchOption === "foo") {
          return "Search by foo… e.g. foo1";
     } else if (searchOption === "bar") {
          return "Search by bar… e.g. bar123";
     } else {
          return "John Smith, 08/23/1970, 123";
     }
};
```

Note: `John Smith, 08/23/1970, 123` is the default placeholder.
Don't forget to wrap the expression in the `{{}}` brackets.